# 英語が残っている：Edit Tag Info

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

タグの編集のボタンに

Edit Tag Info
が残っておりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

「タグ説明の編集」へ更新しました。次回のビルドに適用します。

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/56877930?q=edit%20tag%20info